# Codeigniter 4 Controller Routing Can't Work in Real Live Server

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

My CI V4.3.4 works quite well on localhost but only home/index worked in live server.

I already set as below to ture;

> $routes->setAutoRoute(true);

But I leaved the setting still fale as below, I dnot want add getBefor my method.
such as getTest(), I like test() better. That's why I leaved the setting below to false.

ps: even changed to true stil doesn't work on live server.

> ```
> /**
> * Use improved new auto routing instead of the default legacy version.
> */
> ```
>
> public bool $autoRoutesImproved = false;

My new controller and method as below, I DO noticed the first Uppercase for my controller name .

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

class Demo extends BaseController
{
public function index()
{
    echo 'Demo index';
    //return view('welcome_message');
}

public function test()
{
    echo 'Demo test';

}

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why the localhost worked quite well. But only home index() worked, while other control can't find. really confused. That means the path in  the index.php should be worked now on my live server. Anything I ignored? thanks.

Comment: And I rolled back to using Ver 4.1.9, it worked quite well.

Comment: Version 4.2.0 introduces the more secure auto routing.  If you want to use it, you have to set both setAutoRoute and autoRoutesImproved to true.